# A valid ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a small react js application and I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: exports.render(): A valid
>   ReactComponent must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an
>   array or some other invalid object.

These are my source files: **App.jsx**

```
var React = require('react');
var Chats = require('./chats');
var messages = {
  chatMessages: [{
    name: ' John Doe',
    message: ' Hey Lisa, how are you doing?'
  },{
    name: 'Lisa Johnson',
    message: 'Pretty good, how are you?'
  }]
}
var App = React.createElement(Chats, messages)
React.render(App, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

**Chats.jsx**

```
var React = require ('react');
var Chat = require ('./chat');

var Chats = React.createClass({
  render:function(){
    var chats = this.props.chatMessages.map(function(chatProps){
      return <Chat {...chatProps} />
    });
    return (
      <div>
        {chats}
      </div>
    )
  }
});

module.exports = Chats;
```

And **Chat.jsx**

```
var React = require ('react');

var Chat = React.createClass ({
  render:function (){
  return
    <div>
      <p>{this.props.name}</p>
      <span> {this.props.message} </span>
    </div>

}
});

module.exports = Chat;
```

I think the problem is in my map function but I really want someone to tell me where I made the mistake.

Comment: You returned an array of `Chat` elements from the `Chats` render function; they need a parent element. Try `<div>{chats}</div>` instead (or the JSX-less equivalent).

Comment: Hey Josh, thanks for the comment, after wrapping {chats} into divs the error still persists and also the unique key warning appeared.

Comment: Can you update your code above to reflect the current state? Also, you will need a `key` prop for each item in an array that points to an unique id of some kind so React knows which DOM nodes are for the same data when it renders again.

Comment: I just updated the above code, I will add the unique keys as soon as I get rid of this error :) Thanks

Comment: Try wrapping the tags in parentheses: `return (<div>...</div);` And can you identify which line is causing the error?

Comment: I wrapped it, no changes. Based on the inspector the problem is caused by the React.render in app.jsx line 13 http://prntscr.com/9q76u7

Comment: are you using react v.14?

Comment: No, it's react v.13.3 installed it via npm

Comment: Will you update your code to the present state and add some info about your build process?

Comment: Hmm thought I knew what the issue was, but it's working fine here, https://jsfiddle.net/loktar/69z2wepo/27575/

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller I updated the code also you can find it here: https://github.com/Radu033/chipchat

Loktar this is weird, are you using react 13.3 in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I downloaded your code from GitHub. The problem was, as I suspected, wrapping components in parentheses on the `return`. From your updated code above, you did not do this on the `Chat` component. This is necessary because the transformed value of `React.createElement` will reside on the *next* line after the `return`, never actually running. Here's the altered function:

```js
var Chat = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.props.name}</p>
        <span> {this.props.message} </span>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Also, for what it's worth, your `App` component is redundant. You could just do this:

```
React.render( <Chats {...messages} />, document.querySelector( '.container' ) );
```

Comment: To be more clear—it's not that you have to wrap things in parens, but that the browser will recognize `return` as a statement if you don't put any value after it on the same line, and exit the function.